# Sort multidimensional array and delete duplicates from XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, sorting

What I'm looking to do is sort an array and delete multiple duplicates, heres what I've got:

Im using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to draw in an XML file and turn it into an array, the XML is formatted like this:

```
<Row>

    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">First Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">Address</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">City</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">Province</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">Postal Code</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s17"><Data ss:Type="String">Year</Data></Cell>

</Row>
```

I'm looking to combine the cells first and last name and then compare then to the rest of the array.

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }

    return $results;
}

$simple  = file_get_html('DOM/mail.xml');

$i = 0;

foreach($simple->find('row') as $article) {

    $item['name']     = $article->find('cell', 0)->plaintext.' '.$article->find('cell', 1)->plaintext;

    $item['address']     = $article->find('cell', 2)->plaintext;

    $item['city']     = $article->find('cell', 3)->plaintext;

    $item['province']     = $article->find('cell', 4)->plaintext;

    $item['postal']     = $article->find('cell', 5)->plaintext;

    $item['year']     = $article->find('cell', 6)->plaintext;

    $item['count']     = $i;

    $i++;

    $articles[] = $item;

}

$a[] = "Buckley Terry";
$a[] = "test bar";
$a[] = "Grills Levi";

foreach ($a as $test) {

    $b[] = search($articles, 'name', $test);

}

print_r($b);
```

But all this does is return multiple instances of name. i.e if there is only one entry it will return it. Any help would be awesome.